# Spring Bean Declaration

Tags: spring

I am new to spring so can you please help me understand the below scenario.

I have a bean class which is declared as Bean.

```
class A{

   B anotherClass=new B();

}
```

How is the above code different from the below declaration

```
Class A{
   @Autowire
   B anotherClass;
}
```

Where in the below case I  declare the bean of class B.

Question::

I am aware of the dependency injection and the tight coupling but my real question is part from that if I am declaring the B anotherClass=new B() will it create new instance for the B every time the Bean for class A is called can anyone help me understand the flow.

Comment: The first, you're tied to an implementation. Where the second can be any bean that is a B (i.e. subclass). You should do some searching on Inversion of Control (IoC), and Dependency Injection, and coupling. In the second case, the implementation of B is injected to A by the IoC container, which is this case, Spring. This allows for lesser coupling, as in the first case, it's type coupled

Comment: Hi I am aware of the dependency injection and the tight coupling I was wondering if the class B would have a new instance every time if we call it as new B() instead of creating it as a bean can you please help me understand that.

Comment: You should post that as part of your question.

Comment: Sorry for that my bad, can you please help me understand that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring the 'Bean Container' itself manages creating and referencing instances for you. You can define so called bean **Scopes** that tell spring how to manage a particular bean.

By default a bean has the 'singleton' scope. You can declare a different scope by annotating your class using the `@Scope("scopename")` annotation.

The most commonly used scopes are:

- **singleton**: One instance is shared throughout the entire spring container.
- **protoype**: A fresh instance of the bean is created each time it is referenced.

Have a look at the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html) or [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-bean-scopes-examples/).